# Google Cloud Tasks not executing tasks randomly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

Google Cloud Tasks seems to be unreliable some times. I've added a bunch of tasks and sometimes those are not getting executed.

When I checked the console, it shows '11 Tasks in Queue'. However, those tasks are not listed below (usually it shows correctly).

[image]

Here is how I've created the queue (upsert):

```js
const client = require('./client');

module.exports = async (queue_name, concurrent) => {
  return client.updateQueue({
    queue: {
      name: client.queuePath(
        process.env.GCP_PROJECT,
        process.env.GCP_QUEUE_LOCATION,
        queue_name,
      ),
      rateLimits: {
        maxConcurrentDispatches: concurrent,
        maxDispatchesPerSecond: concurrent,
        maxBurstSize: 100,
      },
      retryConfig: {
        maxAttempts: 3,
        unlimitedAttempts: false,
        maxRetryDuration: {
          seconds: 3600,
        },
        minBackoff: {
          seconds: 60,
        },
        maxBackoff: {
          seconds: 300,
        },
        maxDoublings: 3,
      },
    },
  });
};
```

and here is how I'm adding tasks:

```js
const client = require('./client');

module.exports = async (queue_name, url, config) => {
  return client.createTask({
    parent: client.queuePath(
      process.env.GCP_PROJECT,
      process.env.GCP_QUEUE_LOCATION,
      queue_name,
    ),
    task: {
      httpRequest: {
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        url: `${process.env.OPTIMIZER_URL}/optimize-page`,
        body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ url, config })).toString(
          'base64',
        ),
      },
    },
  });
};
```

The same code works sometimes and sometimes it just got stuck at executing!

Comment: This seems like something internal you could have a better assistance directly from Google. You can make a ticket here: http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=608118&template=1251491

Comment: @asbovelw Thanks. Yes, it looks a bug/error from their site. I've created an issue like you mentioned: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156669139

Comment: You are welcome. I hope it gets resolved soon.